# What is the difference between using /[,]/ and /(|)/ while matching pattern to split in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, split

I'm trying to split variable below to get only the part before ":2|". Why pattern matching to do so works in the variable `@name1`, but not `@name2`?

```
$a = "NB501373:45:HFH3CBGXY:4:11401:17564:1786:2|DS-R2Dec3|Dor|23-12-2013|0m|GFF";

@name1 = split (/(\:1\|DS\-|\:2\|DS\-)/, $a);
@name2 = split (/[\:1\|DS\-,\:2\|DS\-]/, $a);
```

Comment: see regex character classes

Comment: Because the regular expressions used to split are different?

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes

Comment: Why do you expect square brackets to work in the same way as parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the match operator to return the "captured" sections of your regex, then you need to include capturing brackets in your regex.

Capturing brackets are parentheses like `( ... )`.

Square brackets (`[ ... ]`) are used to define character classes. That is, they mean "match any one of the characters between the two brackets". They do not capture text.

Your first example includes capturing brackets - therefore the captured matches are returned and stored in `@name1`.

Your second example includes a character class and no capturing brackets - therefore no matches are returned and stored in `@name2`.

Comment: Maybe spell out explicitly that the character class matches one character which can be ```\ ``` or `:` or `1` or `|` or `D` or `S` or `-` or `2` (with the duplicates removed).

Comment: @tripleee: I thought that's what "match any one of the characters between the two brackets" meant :-)

Comment: It is indeed, but this is a common error and it often seems to require spelling out and rubbing in before the light bulb goes on with  few blinks.